# hibernate.properties not found

Tags: hibernate

Classe GeraTabela com o método main

```
package br.com.drogaria.main;

import br.com.drogaria.util.HibernateUtil;

public class GeraTabela {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        System.out.println();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
        System.out.println("Seção é encerrada pelo método HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();");
    }

}
```

A clase HibernateUtil que interage com hibernate.cfg.xml

```
package br.com.drogaria.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();


    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {


            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            System.out.println("configuração criada!");



            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            System.out.println("hibernate.cfg.xml registrado!");




            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            System.out.println("Seção Criada!");
            System.out.println("método buildSessionFactory() retorna uma sessionFactory a partir do hibernate.cfg.xml");

            return sessionFactory;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Exibe uma mensagem de eerro no console

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    // public class GeraTabela invoca HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        System.out.println("GeraTabela.java invoca o método HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory() para obter uma sessionFactory()");

        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

O arquivo de configuração hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Configurações da conexão -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_drogaria</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">123salmir</property>

        <!-- Pool de conexões JDBC -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Dialeto SQL -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- Gerenciamento da sessão -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Desabilita a cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Exibe os comandos SQL -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!--Cria as tabelas  -->
        <property name="hbm2dd1.auto">update</property> 

        <mapping class="br.com.drogaria.domain.Fabricante" />   
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

A classe de dominio

```
package br.com.drogaria.domain;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_fabricantes")
public class Fabricante {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "fab_codigo")
    private Long codigo;

    @Column(name = "fab_descricao", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String descricao;

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

}
```

log da execução mostrada no console. O hibernate não gera a tabela.

> ago 22, 2017 11:56:46 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO:
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final} ago 22, 2017 11:56:46 AM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found configuração criada! hibernate.cfg.xml
>   registrado! ago 22, 2017 11:56:47 AM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} ago 22, 2017 11:56:47 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) ago 22, 2017 11:56:47 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>   at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_drogaria] ago 22, 2017 11:56:47
>   AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root,
>   password=****} ago 22, 2017 11:56:47 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false ago 22, 2017
>   11:56:47 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections
>    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1) ago
>   22, 2017 11:56:48 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO:
>   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
>   Seção Criada! método buildSessionFactory() retorna uma sessionFactory
>   a partir do hibernate.cfg.xml ago 22, 2017 11:56:49 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   stop INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool
>   [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_drogaria] GeraTabela.java invoca o
>   método HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory() para obter uma
>   sessionFactory()
>
> GeraTabela.java invoca o método HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory() para
>   obter uma sessionFactory() Seção é encerrada pelo método
>   HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();

Comment: Erro de digitação corrigido                                                                                    <!--Cria as tabelas  -->
        <property name="hbm2dd1.auto">update</property>                                                     "hbm2dd1.auto" para "hbm2ddl.auto"

Comment: Resolvido! Para gerar a tabela, tive que usar "dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"